# SVN in XCode corruption of pbxuser

Tags: svn, xcode, version-control

Am new to SVN, so sorry if this is obvious (had no luck Googling it, and been on it for a couple of days).

I have set up a Subversion repository hosted by Unfuddle and all was working well working between my iMac and my MacBook Pro until I got an error message saying the project file had become unreadable.  After deleting my working copies on both machines and checking the project back out I have tracked it down to the fact that my user settings file on my iMac (dave.pbxuser) is showing up with a status of **M** against it, whereas it shows up as **?** on my MacBook.

I thought pbxuser should be part of the global ignore config and should never have an M against it.  If I commit the entire project from the iMac the project file becomes corrupted again.

Is the fact that pbxuser is somehow under source control on the iMac the culprit?  Any ideas how this happened and how to rectify?

Cheers

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have worked around this issue.  Not pretty but it works.  Under the SCM repositories menu, I choose the repository with the project in it that is causing the problem.  It is important that this project is not open at the time.  Find the .xcodeproj file and click on it.  This is actually a wrapper for 3 other files one of which is .pbxuser.  Select the .pbxuser file and delete it from the repository.  To get back up and running, I deleted my working copy and then checked out the whole project again.  Not sure how the pbxuser file got added to source control in the first place, but now it is quite happy with a ? against it on both my machines.

Hope this is some use to someone,

Dave